# How to get a member function pointer in MSVC?

Tags: c++, excel, winapi, visual-c++

I'm not going to get into too much of the details on the Excel side of things, I essentially took code from this example:

[C++ app automates Excel (CppAutomateExcel)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CppAutomateExcel-be36992e/sourcecode?fileId=52564&pathId=816620438)
solution1.cpp

So I've tried this code in MSVC and it compiles:

```
class foo { public: virtual void bar(){} };

int main()
{
    void (foo::*p)() = &foo::bar;
}
```

But similar code to capture the address of the move function in Excel does not work:

```
int main()
{
    Excel::_ApplicationPtr spXlApp;
    HRESULT hr = spXlApp.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Excel::Application));
    Excel::WorkbooksPtr spXlBooks = spXlApp->Workbooks;
    Excel::_WorkbookPtr spXlBook = spXlBooks->Add();
    Excel::_WorksheetPtr spXlSheet = spXlBook->ActiveSheet;
    HRESULT(Excel::_Worksheet::*pMove)(...) = &spXlSheet->Excel::_Worksheet::Move;

    <... irrelevant code ...>

    return 0;
}
```

This has the following compiler error:

> error C2276: '&': illegal operation on bound member function expression

If I remove the `&`, it says I should add it back:

> error C3867: 'Excel::_Worksheet::Move': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member

Any help on what to do here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aren't you working on C++/CLI | Managed C++? If I try your first source, it gives an error of the `public` keyword, as it is not valid C++ syntax!

Comment: @sergiol - there's just a missing colon there, it should be `public:`

Comment: Yes, I know and I tried it with the colon, and code is working fine here. The C++/CLI is a blend of C++ and a C# subset, may be on there not having a colon is a valid syntax!

Comment: @sergiol: C++/CLI extensions are only available, when declaring a `ref class`. For a standard C++ `class`, the standard C++ rules apply, and the colon trailing the `public` keyword is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare the method pointer like this instead:

```
// or whatever parameter type Move() actually uses...
void (Excel::_Worksheet::*pMove)(tagVARIANT, tagVARIANT) = &Excel::_Worksheet::Move;
```

Then, to actually call `pMove()`, you would have to do something like this:

```
Excel::_WorksheetPtr spXlSheet = ...;
(spXlSheet.Get()->*pMove)(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

You say in your question "but similar code..." and then you show code in which you do not do the same thing. Try using the same syntax for setting `pMove` as you used for setting `p` in your smaller example. Try something like `&Excel::_Worksheet::Move;` (without the "spXlSheet->").

If you can specify the specific instance of the object for which to call the function pointer at the time that you set the function pointer as you have there, I'm not aware of such a capability. After dropping `spXlSheet->` from where you set the variable, use it instead where you want to *call* the function pointer.

Comment: Thanks! Given it is a member function I though I could do a shortcut because I want to call pMove with the right object.  essentially binding the object and the function implementation together. It was my understanding that pObject->foo::bar() is equivalent to foo::bar(pObject), which I still think is true, but I think the binding is not possible.